# (VBA) Finding and copying parts of a row in multiple separate worksheets based on matching cell value in active worksheet

Tags: vba, search, automation, copy, relationship

I hope the title wasn't too confusing!

Basically, I have myself an inventory in Excel. I have a worksheet acting as my menu and I have a worksheet for each client (eg, TD Bank, Rogers, Standard Life) which reads as so (in this case, with Videotron as my client):

```
    A           B          C                 D      E            F        G         H
1   CLIENT      UNIQUEID   MATERIALTYPE      SIZE   MATERIALCODE LOCATION QTYPERBOX TOTALQTY
2   Videotron   VID-001    Outgoing Envelope 9x12   VID-OE0812   4-1-3    500       15000
3   Videotron   VID-002    Letterhead        8.5x14 VID-LH0812   1-1-1    2500      50000
4   Videotron   VID-003    Reply Envelope    #9     VID-RE0812   8-5-2    1000      7500
```

The worksheet I need help with is my 'Locations' sheet which contains a list of all the physical locations I have in my warehouse, like so:

```
     A          B        C          D              E      F              G           H
     LOCATION   CLIENT   UNIQUEID   MATERIALTYPE   SIZE   MATERIALCODE   QTYPERBOX   TOTALQTY 
1    1-1-1    
2    1-1-2
3    1-1-3
4    1-2-1
5    1-2-2
6    1-2-3
     etc. etc.
```

For each location there will be an entry in one of the clients worksheets, could be anywhere. If we take the example of physical location '1-1-1' according to the worksheet shown I have a pallet of 50,000 Videotron Letterheads there. What I need the code to do is search for the '1-1-1' in all of the client worksheets and once found to copy the information to columns B:H above in row 1. I then need the same process for location '1-1-2' in row 2 and so on until my last location which for arguments sake is '8-8-3'.

The goal is to have the 'Locations' worksheet populate itself with the correct information taken from the client worksheets which in turn will always give a true reflection of the current physical inventory. This means that if I remove 10,000 envelopes from location '1-1-1' it will automatically update in the 'Locations' worksheet. A similar scenario would be if I physically swapped 2 pallets in my warehouse, let's say I swapped the pallet in location '1-1-1' with the pallet in '2-3-1' and made the change in my client worksheets... I would need the 'Locations' worksheet to reflect the change.

I've looked at many pieces of code, a lot of which I think could help me but it only relates to PART of what I'm trying to achieve and I do not have enough knowledge or understanding to piece them all together in relation to my workbook.

Does anybody think it's possible to get this to work or am I simply dreaming?

EDIT: Should say I'm in Excel 2003.

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible, but it's hard to know what type of help you need.  Do you mainly want a high level algorithm? Do you know how to read cell values into variables in VBA? Do you know how to copy cells from one location to another in VBA, given the locations? Are you familiar with things like If statements and While loops?

Comment: Hi Justin! Well... I know ABOUT the things you mentioned and that I've used similar things in the past albeit at a lot lower level, but unfortunately it has been aided by others. It's my understanding of the programming that lets me down you see. If I have a piece of code I'm usually able to tweak it to my needs just by trial and error with some common sense but to write it from scratch I'm afraid the short answer is... no Sir.

Comment: Does each location have only one item stored there, or could there be multiple items in the same location?

Comment: Good question Tim as it's something that surely happens often enough if we have tiny amounts of stock. For arguments sake let's assume that for now only one specific item would be in a single location. The spreadsheet certainly can keep growing and growing in code but I feel I'm already starting at way higher than basic level! Thanks.

Comment: Could you just sort on column F?

Comment: Sure, but I have over 50 clients and it would be most beneficial if I didn't have to go to each worksheet and re-sort everytime something changes in the physical inventory just to find what's actually in one location. For sure if I had only sheet it would be a lot easier to just sort but my 'Locations' sheet is gathering the information from those 50 or so clients, not 1.

Comment: Would it help if my column headings were in the same order for both the client worksheets and the location worksheet? That way maybe a piece of code like `Cll.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Locations")` could be used?

Comment: Sorry, I have a poor reading skill, but can you label which worksheet is the "Client" worksheet and which one is "Location" worksheet. Are the worksheets stored in the same workbook, what's their naming convention of the "client"/"location" worksheet?

Comment: Is there some reason that you are fighting hard to make a spreadsheet do what a relational database is designed to do?

Comment: I can see some straightforward solutions if you are open to rearranging your data. They don't even use vba, just simple worksheet functions.

Comment: Morning all... OK Larry, all the worksheets are stored in one single workbook. The first example above is a client worksheet and all of the client worksheets are named for the clients, so the above top example is named "Videotron". The second example above is my "Locations" worksheet which is there as the specific overview of the COMPLETE inventory per location in the warehouse.

Dale, there's 2 reasons I'm fighting hard for this! First being that I love Excel and have got it to do many amazing complicated things for me in the past. Second reason being we have no activations for Access here :)

Comment: I'm going to agree with Dale M. You need to make this a database. You can explain it to your boss by trying to outline how much time (labor dollars) you're going to spend trying to force Excel to do something it isn't really supposed to do vs. paying for one license to Access and using the run time compiler to distribute to people. Now, I love Excel too, but there is time and place for it. Dynamic or complex inventory isn't one of them in my opinion. The more complex you make this, the harder it's going to be to convert and scale up when your needs grow. (Speaking from experience :D)

Answer (score 0):

I will still contend it needs to be a database per my comment but I realize that business constraints can veer you off of the most efficient way because this is reality.

Sooo. Maybe you can try something like...

```
Sub sortInventory()
Dim wsInv As Worksheet
Dim wsCust As Worksheet

Dim rngSearch As Range
Dim cellSearch As Range
Dim rngLoc As Range
Dim rngCurLoc As Range

Dim findVal As String

Dim locCol As Integer, custCol As Integer

Dim locFound As Boolean





Set wsInv = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Locations")
Set rngLoc = wsInv.Range("A1", wsInv.Range("A1").End(xlDown))

For Each rngCurLoc In rngLoc.Cells
'This is what you're looking for in each sheet.
    findVal = rngCurLoc.Value
    locFound = False
    For Each wsCust In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If locFound Then Exit For

       'Exclude the location sheet
        If wsCust.Name = "Locations" Then
         Next wsCust
        End If

        Set rngSearch = wsCust.Range("F1", Range("F1").End(xlDown))

        For Each cellSearch In rngSearch.Cells
        'Look for your value
            If cellSearch.Value = findVal Then ''Alternate method could use the "find"
            'Transfer to Locations
            'Use an offset loop to pick/place map to new location.

                 For custCol = 1 To 8 '8 can modify to the width of your data (I think it's 8)
                Select Case custCol
                    Case Is <= 5 'The first 5 are offset by one to the location sheet.
                        wsInv.Cells(rngCurLoc.Row, custCol + 1).Value = wsCust.Cells(cellSearch.Row, custCol).Value
                    Case 6 'Location column
                        ''Do nothing.
                    Case Else 'Direct map
                        wsInv.Cells(rngCurLoc.Row, custCol).Value = wsCust.Cells(cellSearch.Row, custCol).Value
                End Select
            Next custCol
            locFound = True 'This will kick the 2nd loop out to the range loop.
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wsCust
Next rngCurLoc




End Sub
```

I couln't really test it, the tabbing got a bit funny when I pasted it into a codeblock here so the control loops aren't super lined up. It should get you started anyway. It's object and collection heavy but VBA code can get pretty flimsy without strongly defining what you are trying to do.